# $index to display items in list from particular <td>

Tags: html

this is the output format,

```html
                        1.                   Welcome
                        2.          XXX   123    123
                        3.          YYY   456    456
                        4.                   GoodMorning
                        5.          ZZZ   789    789
                        6.                   Thank you
                        7.          QQQ   459    459
```

I do not want to have $index value in Welcome,good morning and thank you rows . I want to display $index value 1,2,3,4 in names rows

Comment: Which flag is used to determine whether to show `td` with text `welecome` or the rest `tds`?

Comment: For the first item in ng-repeat wants to display only welcome message. then next loop iterates and displays other values.

Comment: for eg, names=[ { show: true, welcome }, {name:XXX address: 123 phno :123 }, {YYY address: 456 phno :456 }, {name:ZZZ address: 789 phno :789 },

Comment: First td always be index and next would be welcome but i do not want to display index value to welcome td but next td should start with index value as 1.

Comment: I do not want to have welcome in seperate tr. In ng-repeat what value was there, that should be come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your code to following

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in names">
    <td data-ng-if="$index > 0">{{$index}}</td>
    <td colspan="2" data-ng-if="$index > 0">{{name}}</td>
    <td data-ng-if="$index > 0">{{address}}</td>
    <td data-ng-if="$index > 0">{{mobile}}</td>
    <td data-ng-if="$index == 0" colspan="5">Welcome</td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT**

Here is a working code as per the updated requirement

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names=
  [ { show: true, label : "welcome" },
    {name:"XXX",  address: 123,  phno :123 },
    {name:"YYY",  address: 123,  phno :123 },
    { show: true, label : "goodbye" },
    {name:"AAA",  address: 123,  phno :123 },
    {name:"BBB",  address: 123,  phno :123 }
  ];
  $scope.counter = {index:0};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker">
  <table ng-controller="MainCtrl" border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr ng-repeat="i in names">
      <td data-ng-if="!i.show" data-ng-init="counter.index = counter.index + 1; serialnumber = counter.index">{{serialnumber}}</td>
      <td colspan="2" data-ng-if="!i.show">{{i.name}}</td>
      <td data-ng-if="!i.show">{{i.address}}</td>
      <td data-ng-if="!i.show">{{i.phno}}</td>
      <td data-ng-if="i.show" colspan="5">{{i.label}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: variable "show" holds some other boolean value not related to $index

Comment: @Raghul - Okay. then what is the logic that it is being displayed at the top only. Also, when it is being displayed, what about the other `tds`?

Comment: @Raghul - It should not happen this way. If `welcome` message is at `0` index, it will be displayed first in the list.